# Can I replace my ECM in my 2007 Nissan Quest with a used one

Tags: nissan, electronic-control-module, quest

My Nissan Quest 2007 has a dead ECM and wonder if I can replace it with a used one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but a Nissan Dealership or other qualified shop has to program that ECM to your vehicle.

[image]